# gke-security-groups for subdomain

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We have some troubles getting the RBAC properly working with the *gke-security-groups* approach.

We have a verified subdomain in our Gsuite which we want to use for our gke security groups, i.e. security.example.com. The users reside in example.com and are members of the specific groups, e.g. *security-gke-developers-team1@security.example.com*. The *gke-security-groups@security.example.com* is used in the cluster creation. However, GKE does not seem to properly lookup the group memberships of the users and no helpful log or error message can be found anywhere.

Does anyone know if this approach can even work or if the gke-security-groups do have to be on the same domain as the users, i.e. *gke-security-groups@example.com* instead of *gke-security-groups@security.example.com*?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

gke-security-groups work fine like outlined above. The issue was the visibility of the groups from the G-Suite as the groups have been defined as internal so that only members and owners can see the members of the group. Changing the view permissions to organization solved the issue.